# Can't connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an App Server, my workstation and a SQL Server.

- App Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- Sql Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- Workstation: Windows 7 Enterprise x64

I am using JDBC to connect to SQL Server from my workstation and my app server. My connection string is:

`String strURL="jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME.my.domain\\INSTANCENAME;integratedSecurity=true";`

Works fine from my workstation. Using the same credentials (i.e. logged on interactively to the app server), I get this error returned:

`SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.`

The app server and the workstation and the sql server are all in the same domain and are logging on with the same credentials, and using the same connection string from the same block of code. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure the application server is running under a domain account, and not a local machine account?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I created a separate java application to isolate this and logged onto the server interactively and got the same error. I don't get the error on a different server in the same domain. So, there's something wrong with the server, but I'm not sure what, or where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it because we had a buggy Java installation. Installed a new Java home and it worked fine.